# rails query(SQL) select the index after ordering?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to find the rank of a user, ordered by an arbitrary `score`

something like:

```
score_rank = User.order(score: :desc).select("id, the_index_of_the_ordering").find(person_id)
other_rank = User.order(other: :desc).select("id, the_index_of_the_ordering").find(person_id)
```

Comment: If you're doing a `find` on the end, the ordering really doesn't matter - just select in the default order.

Comment: @meagar that duplicate question doesn't have an accepted question!

Comment: @BlairAnderson It doesn't have to, to be a duplicate.